# ANTLR: How to preserve data in tree between multiple tree grammars

Tags: compiler-construction, tree, antlr

I want to create a very simple translator that translates some source code defined by the language into assembly. I have already created the lexer and parser which produces an AST. I have created a tree grammar which traverses the tree and keeps track of things like declared variables using dynamic scopes.

The problem is I can't simply create a translator using one tree grammar because I need to traverse the tree in multiple passes. The first pass will be semantic analysis, and the second pass will be translation into assembly. Each pass will be a different tree grammar.

My question is, how do I preserve node-specific information from the semantic analysis pass in the tree so that I can access it for the translation pass? How do I annotate the tree? Is there a way I can assign information to the individual nodes in the tree? Do I need to create a custom tree node class for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to create a custom tree node class for this?

Yes.

See:

- [Extend ANTLR3 AST's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635729/extend-antlr3-asts)
- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction